How to configure postfix to pipe all incoming email to a script using Plesk?
Basically, I'd like the same functionality as in the question below. I only run into the issue that whenever I add
transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport, hash:/etc/postfix/transport

to the main.cf file, indeed the script gets executed, but the email will no longer be stored in the inbox. I'd like to keep it as a backup. How can I achieve this?
https://serverfault.com/questions/258469/how-to-configure-postfix-to-pipe-all-incoming-email-to-a-script
